# THREE.js Rotate Object by Mouse-Vector

Tags: javascript, rotation, three.js, quaternions, onmousemove

I want to build something simular (http://www.goat1000.com/tagcanvas.php) with THREE.js (Rotate an Objekt continuously via Mouse-Vector without any jitter, gaps, interruption or something else)...

Im not gettin into it - tried a few different scenrios (simply rotate each axis by its own, tried slerp and quaternion).

You find some of my experiments on fiddler.
Slerp (looks exact like lookAt() ): http://jsfiddle.net/DLta8/

```
var v = new THREE.Vector3( mouse2D.y, -mouse2D.x, 0 );
var q = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromEuler( v );
var newQuaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();
THREE.Quaternion.slerp( mesh.quaternion, q, newQuaternion, 0.07 );
mesh.quaternion = newQuaternion;
mesh.quaternion.normalize();
```

Quaternion (looks good but the reset to quaternion.set( 0, 0, 0, 1 ) sucks): http://jsfiddle.net/vYvmk/

```
var step = .025;    
var rotateQuaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();
rotateQuaternion.setFromAxisAngle( vector, step );
mesh.quaternion.multiplySelf( rotateQuaternion );
mesh.quaternion.normalize();
```

Any hints?